# Find out if an Apache module can be disabled from website usage

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, logging

I can see the list of core and other modules loaded by apache using the below command:

```
$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
```

In order to optimize the performance of the server (save memory on each `Apache` thread essentially), I would like to disable unused modules. The `Apache` documentation provides information about this modules at the [following page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/).

Most of the time, the information provided for each module is enough to determine whether I should disable a module or not. For instance I know I don't use `LDAP` authentication so I can safely disable `authnz_ldap_module`.

However for some modules it is a bit less obvious. For instance the [`mime_magic`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) module is used as a "second line of defense" for cases that [`mod_mime`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) can't resolve, which can't be determined theoretically as it depends on what files will get served by Apache.

**Q: Is there a way to log to a file the list of modules that `Apache` effectively used to process a request?**

If I could log such information, I would just let the web server run for some time, then get the list of modules that were used to process all the requests received in the meantime, and disable those that don't appear in that list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you determine which Apache modules have been used and can be removed?](http://serverfault.com/questions/325781/can-you-determine-which-apache-modules-have-been-used-and-can-be-removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a universal solution, but there are still
some options.  Some modules (for instance, `mod_rewrite`) have their
own logging facilities, but you'd have to read the documentation for
each module to find out.  Any modules listed as `static` are compiled
in and can't be disabled unless you recompile Apache.  For the rest,
you might try three things: searching for directive prefixes, enabling
debug logging, or selectively disabling module-by-module and
restarting.

For most modules, the directives share a common prefix.  For the HTTP
authentication modules, `basic` and `digest`, you can tell if you're
using them by filtering the configuration files with `grep`.  If
you're doing virtual hosting you can probably do the following:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
grep Auth *
```

If you see anything like `AuthType basic` or `AuthType digest`, then
you need one or both of these modules.  Otherwise, it should be safe
to disable them.  Similarly for other modules: `mime_magic` is only
enabled if the `MimeMagicFile` directive is issued somewhere.

If there are modules you're still not sure about after that, you might
try enabling `LogLevel debug` and checking the logs.  If you see some
output from a module, then you can tell that the module is in use.
You can even [set LogLevel debug for specific modules](https://serverfault.com/questions/158039/apache-configure-loglevel-debug-for-certain-modules-only).
This is slightly different than what you asked about though, since if
you don't see any output, it doesn't necessarily mean that a module is
not in use.  (Maybe it simply doesn't produce debug output.)

Finally, in many cases you can try disabling a module and running
`apache2ctl configtest`.  If a directive is not recognized because a
module isn't being loaded, this will result in error.

Comment: So far I've been checking for module-related directives to see if I could disable a module. Better than restarting apache and find out it doesn't start up again because a module that is being used has been disabled: use `apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: Yes, that's much better--thanks. I've updated the answer.